# Accessing WebIOPi over internet - Port forwarding

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, portforwarding, webiopi

I was able to set up  the WebIOPi on my Respberry Pi and able to view my sensors/data by visiting https://192.168.2.10:8000 on my local network. All seems to be working great. I also went into my router settings to set port forwarding for the Pi's IP address with starting/ending port 8000. So my issue is when I went to my school and typed in my **external IP address** (Routers Address) with the port, like so:

```
https:/// 152.xx.xxx.xxx:8000
```

I wasn't able to view the webpage that I was able to do so over my Local network. I have little knowledge in networking, I thought by setting up port forwarding would allow me to access my Pi from anywhere over the internet. Kindly if any one can share what I might be missing! I was following this guide as it says in the end that if you want to view your device over the internet just enable port forwarding. 
http://forums.connectedly.com/raspberry-pi-f179/how-controlling-gpio-pins-via-internet-2884/

Any help would be much appreciated! Happy New year!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, The whole issue was in the router itself, I managed to call my ISP and they helped me setup Port Forwarding.